# Java If NoSuchElementException is returned

Tags: java, if-statement

How can I make an if statement to check if "NoSuchElementException" is returned from a function? Something similar to what I have below.

```
if (functionReturns == "NoSuchElementException")
```

Comment: Read on exceptions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Why don't you just catch it?

Comment: I have a try and catch in my function. I'm trying to see what it returns from another class.

Comment: @SourceCode Does your method declare that it `throws NoSuchElementException`? If not, its a bit tricky.

Comment: @SourceCode what does it return and do you want to perform only if exception is thrown?

Comment: Thanks guys but I found the answer. if(function.equals("NoSuchElementException")) worked because I just want to check what the try-catch returns.

Comment: So this was really a question about how to test equality of string values? If so, it's better to use the idiom "String Literal".equals(someVariable) since you avoid having to do null checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way worked for me.

```
if(function.equals("NoSuchElementException"))
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This is the answer to my question. I posted it here so hopefully it will help someone else. I just have to wait two days so I can select it as the correct answer. @vandale

Answer (score 6):

> How can I make an if statement to check if NoSuchElementException" is
>   returned from a function?

If you meant that your function returns a `String` with the value as *NoSuchElementException*, use `equals` instead of `==` :

```
if("NoSuchElementException".equals(functionReturns)) { }
```

If you meant that your function can `throw` a `NoSuchElementException`, use a `try-catch`. The `catch` block will be triggered when the function throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

```
try {
    function();
} catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
     //NoSuchElementException was thrown

}
```

If you meant that your function actually returns an instance of `NoSuchElementException`, you can use :

```
NoSuchElementException.class.isAssignableFrom(functionReturns)
```

Answer (score 1):

If method is throwing exception then simple use try and catch .

like

```
 boolean isException = false;
    try{
        //method that throws
    }catch(NoSuchElementException e){

      isException = true;
    //or perform what you like
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `NoSuchElementException` or any other `Exception` is basically *Thrown* by a method not *Returned*. So you can/should not check it via `return` type.
The best approach to handle any type of `Exception` is `try catch` blocks.  Ex:-

```
 try {
   // Probable Exception Throwing code
} catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
     // handle/log specific type of error
}
catch(Exception e) {
     // handle/log Generic error if none specific is defined
}
```

Find more about `Exception` in the Official Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using if statement then there must be thrown more than one error so in java 7
In Java 7 it was made possible to catch multiple different exceptions in the same catch block. This is also known as multi catch.

Before Java 7 you would write something like this:

```
try {

    // execute code that may throw 1 of the 3 exceptions below.

} catch(NoSuchElementException e) {//work as if if (functionReturns == "NoSuchElementException")
    logger.log(e);

} catch(NoSuchElementException1 e) {//work as if if (functionReturns == "NoSuchElementException1")
    logger.log(e);

} catch(NoSuchElementException2 e) {//work as if if (functionReturns == "NoSuchElementException2")
    logger.severe(e);
}
```

As you can see, the two exceptions NoSuchElementException1 and NoSuchElementException2 are handled in the same way, but you still have to write two individual catch blocks for them.

In Java 7 you can catch multiple exceptions using the multi catch syntax:

```
try {

    // execute code that may throw 1 of the 3 exceptions below.
//combind way to catch multiple error
} catch(NoSuchElementException1 | NoSuchElementException2 e) {
    logger.log(e);

} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.severe(e);
}
```

Notice how the two exception class names in the first catch block are separated by the pipe character |. The pipe character between exception class names is how you declare multiple exceptions to be caught by the same catch clause.